# My request body is encoded in UTF-8 which causes a web service to deny it. What are my options?

Tags: c#, utf-8, httpwebrequest

I am trying to obtain a token from a Web Service (Salesforce Commerce Cloud) however because my web client is encoding the request in UTF-8, the Content-Length is coming up as 82 characters.. not 79. Because of this, the web service is throwing an error.

I tried changing the header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8` however that had no effect.

If I change my WebClient from `new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8))` to `new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))`, the request is successful, however I am reluctant to change that because I have other things using that WebClient and don't yet know how they will handle that change.

Without adding overloads or anything to my WebClient, is there another generally accepted practice for telling the remote web service to encoding of my data that may make it accept it? I'm assuming this largely depends on the implementation of the web service itself.

This is the method I'm using for sending the request:

```
public HttpResponseData SendRequestWithBody(HttpMethod httpMethod, string url, Dictionary<string, string> headers, string contentType, string body)
{
    logger.InfoFormat("Sending {0} request to url={1}", httpMethod.Method, url);

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateHttpWebRequest(url, headers);
    webRequest.ContentType = contentType;
    webRequest.Method = httpMethod.Method;
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

    if (this.webRequestLogger != null)
    {
        webRequestLogger.LogRequest(webRequest, webClientRequestLoggerTime, body);
    }

    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(body);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }

    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    HttpResponseData httpResponseData = CreateHttpResponseData(httpWebResponse);
    if (this.webRequestLogger != null)
    {
        webRequestLogger.LogResponse(httpResponseData, webClientRequestLoggerTime);
    }

    return httpResponseData;
}

    private HttpWebRequest CreateHttpWebRequest(string requestUrl, Dictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        webRequest.Timeout = requestTimeoutInSeconds * 1000;

        if (headers != null && headers.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in headers)
            {
                if (header.Key == HttpHeaderContentTypeName)
                    webRequest.ContentType = header.Value;
                else if (header.Key == HttpHeaderAcceptName)
                    webRequest.Accept = header.Value;
                else
                    webRequest.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
        }

        return webRequest;
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the complete code of your webRequest so we can test it ?

Comment: You won't be able to test it - its a private API.

Comment: I can't see any line sets the ContentLength of your request

Comment: I believe the `Content-Length` is handled by the framework -
 `(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);`,

Comment: I don't know if framework handles the request by itself or not. but I usually just set it manually.

Comment: You may use fiddler to check the sent data by your app

Comment: I know the data that is being sent.. as the question states my problem is the Content-Length its sending. I'll set manually just for this request.

Comment: Fiddler isn't used to just know if the data is sent or not, You will use it to analyze the data. It will help you to see the value of ContentLength.
Also try to make your code minimum as possible for testing problems like this.

Comment: Because comments can't handle many characters. Check this:
https://pastebin.com/h2JJr12g